# How to determine the initial value of the inflaton field, and how to set pivot scale?

Tags: cosmology, differential-equations

First and second slow-roll parameters are given by
\begin{equation}
    \epsilon(\phi)\equiv\frac{M_{P}^{2}}{16\pi}\left(\frac{V^{\prime}(\phi)}{V(\phi)}\right)^{2}, \hspace{1.5cm} \eta(\phi)\equiv\frac{M_{P}^{2}}{8\pi}\left(\frac{V^{\prime \prime}(\phi)}{V(\phi)}\right). 
\end{equation}
inflation ends if $ \epsilon(\phi)=1$.
Now number of e-folds $N$ are defined by
\begin{equation}
    N=2\sqrt{\pi}\int_{\phi_{end}}^{\phi_{in}}\frac{d\phi^{\prime}}{\sqrt{\epsilon(\phi^{\prime})}}.
\end{equation}

suppose I want to generate the 70 number of e-folds, then what should be the $\phi_{in}$, for any arbitrary potential for example $\begin{equation}\label{potentialchoice}
V(\phi)=a\phi+\frac{b}{2}\phi^{2}+\frac{c}{4}\phi^{4}?
\end{equation}$

Generally if we take quadratic potential then $\phi_{in}=16Mpl$ can produce about 70 e-folds for inflation.

Beside that that I want to know how to set pivot scale $k=0.05Mpl^{-1}$ at any arbitrary number of e-folds for example 15 number of e-folds.

where $Mpl$ is Planck mass, $a$,$b$,$c$ are arbitrary constants.